# twitter button javascript not showing

Tags: javascript, html

This is a fairly simple problem but I cannot seem to get it to work. I want to add a "follow" twitter button on my website but with no luck. It only shows the link and not the nice fancy button.

This is the code I used. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en" data-size="small">Follow @Twitter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first the link is shown, but then the JavaScript kicks in and replaces it with the nice fancy button. I've just tried your code exactly and it works for me.

Perhaps, you have JavaScript disabled in your browser, or maybe the JavaScript cannot make a connection to twitter from your machine for some reason?

If JavaScript is enabled, to test the connection to Twitter, try hitting http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js and ensure a JavaScript file is returned.